# Master Page Upgrading SharePoint 2013 to 2016

Tags: 2013, master-page, upgrade, 2016

I have done plenty of research and cannot find a clear answer.  Of course you can expect some issues when performing SharePoint migrations but I cannot find a direct answer on the issues that may happen when migrating master pages and wiki pages from SP 2013 to 2016.

- When migrating from SP 2010 to 2013 Master Page would reset to the default master page.  Will this do the same when migrating from SP 2013 to 2016?
- Will script web parts (and other web parts (ex. content editor, preview web parts...etc.)) need to be added again in 2016 because it's not apart of the custom branding or do they transfer over?
- Will custom style sheets (not apart of the default master) transfer over or work in SP 2016?

Any help is welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Did anyone ever come up with an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences every migration can be a little different even if it looks like the same setup of farm and environment. What I always do and recommending to You now is to do **Test migration**. *You can check everything what you think could be problem after migration process.*

But I think that your Webparts and Master Pages will work correctly and there won't be any change. You should use Upgrade-SPsite command on SP 2016. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Upgrade-SPSite?view=sharepoint-ps

Besides here are some notes for site collections upgrade: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/troubleshoot-site-collection-upgrade-issues